# How can I selectively copy preferences from one machine to another?

Tags: preferences

How can I selectively copy app preferences from an older machine to a newer one?

- Is it sufficient to copy the preferences files from (e.g.) `~/Library/Preferences`?
- Will there be any side effects to doing that?
- Will I need to ensure that apps care closed when I copy the file?
- Will I need to reboot to flush anything from memory?

If the above approach does in fact work, is there an easier way?  I've tried the app SyncSettings but was not able to get it working *at all for any app preferences at all*.  And I haven't found any other apps that claim to do the same thing.

***Please do not tell me to use migration assistant.***  I have **huge** amounts of stuff on my old machine and one of the benefits of a new machine is a fresh start.  If I copy **everything** over, I not only delete stuff on my new machine that I want to keep, but I keep everything from the old machine that I don't want.  Lose-Lose.

I am looking for a solution that allows **selectively** moving preferences over.

Answer (score 2):

There is no rigid standard on macOS for location of preference files, nor of data.  This is particularly true for apps from outside the App Store.

- Is it sufficient to copy the preferences files from
  `~/Library/Preferences`?

Only if the app keeps its preferences in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Some apps will have preferences inside: `~/Library/Containers', or '~/Library/Application Support`

- Will there be any side effects to doing that?

There could be. For example, a preference which points to a physical location in the file system.

The app may also keep data in other locations within `~/Library`. If you are lucky in `~/Library/Application Support`, but could be elsewhere. Further, if an app has computer wide (not just user) data, it may keep preferences and files (e.g. licenses) in `/Library` or somewhere in `/Users`.

Licenses can be particularly tricky as they are often partially hidden.

- Will I need to ensure that apps are closed when I copy the file?

Safer to make sure that the app is closed. Probably not essential.

- Will I need to reboot to flush anything from memory?

In most cases no, but it could a wise precaution.

**Further thoughts**

I hope I have convinced you that there is no guaranteed way of transferring the required data from one computer to another.  Even Migration Assistant is not 100% - it is only an *assistant*.

Though a few apps will be easy to transfer, you will need to check each one as you go.

But I do favour the "fresh start" approach to a new computer. Make sure you have all your license information before you start.

Answer (score 0):

How is the selection to be made, if not manually?

Share the `~/Library` folder on one of the computers, and then sit at one computer with two Finder windows, one for each library, comparing and transferring the contents of each folder, systematically.

Comment: I would manually select the apps I want to copy the preferences for.  But I don't want to manually click every checkbox etc. in the preference UI for each app.